# Integrating Laravel framework within Yii

Tags: php, laravel, yii

I've built a web application using Yii, and my client has provided me with a white-labeled application built using Laravel 5. I considered converting the Laravel code to Yii, but this task seems challenging and time-consuming.

I'm contemplating the possibility of installing Laravel within the Yii framework. Is this feasible? If not, do you have any alternative suggestions?

Comment: How do you want the Laravel application and Yii application to interact?

Answer (score 0):

Both frameworks depending on the database tables so you can integrate both solutions and make database bridge, But there is noway currently to make integration between the router in both framework.

Answer (score 0):

This extension allows running Yii2 and Laravel applications simultaneously at the same project, facilitating graceful migration from Yii2 to Laravel.

This is what you need mate [Link](https://github.com/yii2tech/illuminate)